# OpenGL scene to equirectangular panorama

Tags: opengl, opencv, opengl-3, panoramas

I have a ladybug camera from Point Grey that I'm using under Linux. It's a panoramic (multi)camera (5 camera to do the lateral 360º and 1 camera looking up). Reusing some of the code from the LadybugSDK (only for Windows) I'm able to show an OpenGL "scene" with all the images from the different cameras stitched.
I would like to transform and save this OpenGL "scene" into a equirectangular panoramic image like:
[image: Radial Porjection]

For all the 3D points (X,Y,Z) it's possible to find theta and phi coordinate like:

[image: Radial Picture Equation]

Having this equirectangular panoramic image would allow me to view that panoramas on the internet using for example flash applications.

How could I do that?